# XSLT 1.0 build newline-delimited list using IFs and remove last newline

Tags: xml, xslt, newline

The XML source has data that I want to convert into one list delimited by newline characters and eliminate the last newline.

This is what I have so far...

XML

```
<pool>yes</pool>
<balcony>no</balcony>
<garage>yes</garage>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:variable name="pool"><xsl:if test="pool='yes'"><xsl:text>Pool&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:if></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="balcony"><xsl:if test="balcony='yes'"><xsl:text>Balcony&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:if></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="garage"><xsl:if test="garage='yes'"><xsl:text>Garage&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:if></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="features"><xsl:value-of select="concat($pool,$balcony,$garage)"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$features"/>
```

At this point I have:

```
Pool<newline>
Garage<newline>
blank line
```

I want to remove that last newline and blank line.

Is there a way to get rid of that, or change how I put the list together in order to produce the list?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<features>
    <pool>yes</pool>
    <balcony>no</balcony>
    <garage>yes</garage>
</features>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="features">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[.='yes']">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
pool
garage
```

---

To do it your way, you could simply remove the last newline character:

```
<xsl:template match="features">
    <xsl:variable name="pool">
        <xsl:if test="pool='yes'">
            <xsl:text>Pool&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="balcony">
        <xsl:if test="balcony='yes'">
            <xsl:text>Balcony&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="garage">
        <xsl:if test="garage='yes'">
            <xsl:text>Garage&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="features" select="concat($pool, $balcony, $garage)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($features, 1, string-length($features) - 1)"/>
</xsl:template>
```